# How to retrieve specific analysisTypes from Druid Segment Metadata Queries

Tags: metadata, druid

How to retrieve the specific identifiers of all the columns from druid segmentMetadata metdata queries.I was expecting the result to contain only cardinality and size ,but all the analyses are returned.

```
{
  "queryType":"segmentMetadata",
  "dataSource":"wikiticker",
  "intervals":["2015-09-1/2015-09-13"],
  "analysisTypes":["cardinality","size"]
}
```

But still all the analyses of all columns are returned in the result.
    Actual result:

```
"user_unique" : {
      "type" : "hyperUnique",
      "hasMultipleValues" : false,
      "size" : 0,
      "cardinality" : null,
      "minValue" : null,
      "maxValue" : null,
      "errorMessage" : null
    }
```

Expected result:

```
"user_unique" : {      
      "size" : 0,
      "cardinality" : null
   }
```

Comment: What is the rest point you used to get that result ?

Answer (score 0):

analysisTypes was introduced to speedup the query by omitting the computation of the excluded properties. So having a the result that contains null seems the expected behavior.